# Set ClientID to static in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a C# code where I am setting the ID of a DIV.

Example:

```
div.ID = "slider";
```

The only issue is when the website loads ASP adds a whole bunch of random characters in front of the ID. I cannot use the `<% Page %>` because I am just using a Web Part.

When I tried to set:

```
div.ClientID = "static";
```

I am given an error where the property is read only.

Is there any other way to set it within C#, so the ID does not change when the website runs my page?

I do not want to use `<%= slider.ClientID  %>` in the javascript/css code but if that's the only way then I guess I have no choice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are looking for [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, not `ClientID`

```
div.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
```

If you want to define it in aspx page then you can do:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" ></div>
```

Remember it is provided with .Net framework 4.0 and above.

Comment: Figured. I am only running 3.5 :/. Too bad it's not backward compatible!!! Thanks :) I will most likely upgrade than.

Comment: @SiKni8, Its better if you upgrade but do look at the [breaking changes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET4BreakingChangesAndStuffToBeAwareOf.aspx)